# There's a way to have hide header (in mobile) when open page and show it when scroll down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

i'm developing a website with elementor pro and wordpress and my client would like that when the website opens (but only in mobile and in homepage) there is the image of the homepage (it is a slide) in full screen and when you scroll down the header appears fix at the top without scroll. It's possible to do it? If so, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: firs though, CSS `position:sticky` could help

Comment: thanks for your answer, you mean add this string code in css?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It was a comment, not an answer, and yes, that's a property you would use on some selector in your CSS ... I don't know which selector, how could I, I can't see your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to achieve the same for the mobile device.

```
@media and (max-width: 767) { 
      .header-area {
        position: sticky;
        top : 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Great to hear it worked. !